# What ways can I receive diamonds (premium currency) in Runes of Magic?

Tags: runes-of-magic

Are there any other ways to get or earn Diamonds in Runes of Magic?

I see there's a category for Diamonds in the Auction House, but has anyone seen Diamonds for sale?  If so, what did they fetch?

Are there any quests or drops that yield Diamonds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately Score for More has been closed.
[See this link for more info](http://board.us.runesofmagic.gameforge.com/board272-runes-of-magic-us-au/board265-news-announcements/board267-news-announcements/80776-the-end-of-score-for-more/)**

---

**Yes** there is now a way to **earn** diamond for Runes of Magic. Frogster have recently introduced an Loyalty system.

You can now register an **Score for More**(SFM) account [here](http://www.scoreformore.net).

The account is linked to an in-game character, and based on that character's activity you earn points on your SFM account, which in turn you can then redeem to upgrade your SFM "level" and also redeem for in game items.

Please note that once you link a character you cannot unlink it. so pick one you will be using, also you will receive points based on the current level of your character so you don't have to start from scratch.

Here is a breakdown of how earning diamonds work:

> Every month, Gold members will receive     15 Diamonds
> Every month, Platinum members will receive     40 Diamonds
> Every month, Royal Black members will receive  100 Diamonds

And a quote from their FAQ:

> How can I get free Diamonds?
>
> Particularly active players receive free Diamonds, depending on their Score for More status. For every
> full month (30 days) in which your Action Score account balance
> increases, you can receive a Diamond package the following month. Your
> Action Score account balance increases, for example, when you log into
> the game, by 5 AS. The size of the package varies with your status.
> Beginners and Silver members do not receive any Diamonds. Gold members
> can earn 15 Diamonds per month. Platinum members can get 40 Diamonds
> credited to their account, and once you’ve achieved Royal Black
> status, we'll give you a whopping 100 Diamonds for each month in which
> you've been active in the game. If your status makes you eligible for
> Diamond packages, you will receive your first one after your first
> full month of Score for More activity, on the 1st of the following
> month.
>
> Examples:
>
> - If you activated your Score for More account on 08/12/2011 and were active in January, you will receive a Diamond package on the 1st of
>   February 2012 (dependent on your status)
> - If you activated your Score for More account on 31/12/2011 and were active in January, you will receive a Diamond package on the 1st of
>   February 2012 (dependent on your status)
> - If you activated your Score for More account on 08/12/2011 and were active in December but not in January, you will not receive a Diamond
>   package

Comment: Has anyone actually tried this, seems a little sketchy having to enter your account password and such

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to acquire diamonds is to buy them. In the past, you used to be able to purchase diamonds on the Auction House with gold, but this was supposedly changed due to the amount of "gold farmer bots."